# How to extract hyperlinks from table cells in row/column loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a JS function that writes the contents of a table on the page to a CSV file.

However, whenever I come across a table cell that has a hyperlink (e.g., `<td><a href="https://www.example.com>Cell Value 1</a></td>`), I need to write the href value (https://www.example.com in this case) and *not* the html text (Cell Value 1 in this case)

The code below shows a function that loops over rows and then columns. I have no problems creating a CSV this way, but am struggling to implement the "check" for `<a href="">` values.

```
<script>
    function downloadCSV() {
        var table = document.getElementById("table-example");

        // Array of rowData arrays
        var results = []; 
        // holds data from each table row
        var rowData;

       //iterate through rows, skipping header 
        for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            rowData = [];

            //iterate through columns
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

                // Checking for href and extracing link
                let link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                console.log(link);

                if () {
                     ....
                }

                else {
                    rowData.push(col.textContent);
                }   
            }
            results.push(rowData);  
        }
```

If needed, a sample table is:

```html
<button onClick="downloadCSV()">Download CSV</button>

<table id="table-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.example.com">Tiger Nixon</a></td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

My goal was to implement an if-else where I would add the value of the `href` to the array is the table cell had one, or add the html text if not. However, the `link` variable is always undefined, even while iterating on a column that I know has an `<a href="">`.

**Edit**:

Following Taplar's suggestion that using `$(this)` in the for-loop was misguided, I came up with the following solution:

```
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

                // Checking for href and extracing link
                var links = col.getElementsByTagName('a');

                if (links.length > 0) {
                    var cellData = links[0].getAttribute('href');
                } else {
                    var cellData = col.textContent;
                }

                rowData.push(cellData);
```

Comment: `for` loops do not adjust what `this` points to.  I would assume you need to use `col`, rather than `this`, in some fashion

Comment: @Taplar Thank you - I edited the post to show my solution without using `$(this)`.

Comment: @Ahmed if you were able to answer your own question, feel free to post it as an answer rather than an edit (and mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was the following:

```
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

            // Checking for href and extracing link
            var links = col.getElementsByTagName('a');

            if (links.length > 0) {
                var cellData = links[0].getAttribute('href');
            } else {
                var cellData = col.textContent;
            }

            rowData.push(cellData);
```

Answer (score 2):

I aggree with Taplar about `this`. 
Bellow i think is what you are looking for.

```js
function downloadCSV() {

  var table = document.getElementById("table-example");

  // Array of rowData arrays
  var results = [];
  // holds data from each table row
  var rowData;

  for (var i = 1; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    rowData = [];

    //iterate through columns
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      var cell = $(row.cells[j]);

      var hashref = cell.find('a');
      // Cause it get a collection
      if (hashref.length > 0 && hashref.length === 1) {
        rowData.push(hashref.attr('href'));
      } else {
        rowData.push(col.textContent);
      }
    } // end for cell
    results.push(rowData);
  } // end row

  console.log(results);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="downloadCSV()">Download CSV</button>

<table id="table-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://www.example.com">Tiger Nixon</a></td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks George! I came up with a very similar solution after Taplar's comment. It seems the only difference is I used `getElementsByTagName` where you used jQuery, and you added a check for `length === 1` where I only checked `length > 0`.

Comment: @Ahmed you can do it all with jquery instead of using 'getElementsByTagName'  or "getElementById"you can use $('#table-example') etc etc. I just thought you use jquery for href thats why i used it only there.